# Is the "low talker" actually talking or just mumbling nonsense?

Tags: production, seinfeld

In the classic "Puffy Shirt" episode of Seinfeld, Jerry accidentally promises "low talker" [**Leslie**](http://seinfeld.wikia.com/wiki/Leslie) to wear her shirt design on The Today Show. Both in this episode and during her appearance in the finale, Leslie speaks so softly that it sounds like she's mumbling, and consequently nobody can understand what she's saying.

**Is the actress (Wendel Mendrum) actually speaking her lines that softly, or is she in reality just mumbling nonsense?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the script](http://www.seinfeldscripts.com/ThePuffyShirt.htm), Leslie doesn't have any actual words for her parts.  In fact, her name doesn't appear next to any parts where words are actually spoken.  Her parts say something like:

> (Leslie starts 'talking', Kramer laughs. Jerry and Elaine have no clue what she's saying. They lean closer)

Listening closely to [the scene](https://youtu.be/BFRoXoh6aks?t=12s), it does sounds like she is just mumbling incomprehensible words, especially during the first time she "speaks."

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you are not linking to the script, but a __transcript__, i.e. it was transcribed by fans who watched to episode. Therefore it can't be used as "proof" that the low talker doesn't say anything real.